# Как установить свою иконку приложения python

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

Я разрабатываю приложение и мне нужно установить свою иконку. Использую customtkinter. На форумах говорили, что иконка устанавливается также, как и в обычном tkinter, но у меня получилось только с помощью pillow.

```
    self.wm_iconbitmap()
    icopath = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="../JustLan/images/send-message.ico")
    self.iconphoto(False, icopath)
```

Но так иконка устанавливается только в левый верхний угол приложения, а в панели задач не отображается. Подскажите что можно сделать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я хочу установить иконку через iconbitmap, то выдается ошибка

**bitmap "../JustLan/images/send-message.ico" not defined**